# Is it possible to edit the path and view the folder path in the Finder?

Tags: finder, switching, filesystem

I'm not sure what it is called on the Mac, but when I open my Downloads folder (or any other folder), I'm referring to this file explorer window that shows me my file structure.

I know there are options, like I can view my files and folders in panes, or in a detail view, etc.

But what I hate is that I can't modify the current path location easily, nor can I cut and paste the current folder path.

This really drives me nuts, I wish it could be more like Windows's file explorer as it is so easy and intuitive to use.

Is there a hidden option for these 2 issues that I am missing?

Comment: It's called a *Finder window*.

Comment: [A similar question at Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/174297/address-bar-in-finder)

Answer (score 17):

Finder does not have a bar like in the explorer on Windows, but there are some things you can do to achieve similar results.

To have the current path always visible, open a window and go to View > Show Path Bar. This will add a bar to the bottom of your windows which shows the path of the selected file, the same as if you were in search view. You can also Command-Click on the icon at the top of the window to view the path as a menu. As noted by @lhf, copying a file will also copy its path. You can also drag a file from the window or path bar to most places where a file or path is expected, such as open or save dialogs.

To go to a folder based on its path, press <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>. This will pop up a box where you can type in a path, and either the current or a new window will open at that path. This also works in open and save dialogs.

Answer (score 8):

Try [FinderPath](http://bahoom.com/finderpath/)

[image]

> A Finder addition that displays a small address bar in Finder windows.

Comment: This doesnt work on El Capitan.

Comment: @jdln - Apple seems dead-set on ruining OS X.

Comment: Works for me on Sierra.

Comment: @dorien Did you have to do anything special to get it to work on Sierra?

Comment: Working on High Sierra

Comment: Working fantastically with macOS 13.3.1. The official website is offline so you must download from here: https://web.archive.org/web/20230128154224/http://bahoom.com/finderpath/

Answer (score 5):

You can drag the icon at the top center of the window to a Terminal window and get the path.

Selecting and copying a folder or document in a Finder window also saves the path so that when you paste it in a Terminal window you get the path.

Command-click the top center icon also allows you to navigate up in the path.

Answer (score 2):

1. While in any Finder window
2. Press <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>﻿﻿+<kbd>G</kbd>﻿﻿
3. Type or paste
   your destination in the window.
4. Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

That's it :)

This is especially useful inside "not full" Finder windows. For example if you need to add a specific hidden path  ~/Library/Application Support, while inside Spotlight settings (like I needed the other day), so it doesn't get indexed. Using <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>﻿﻿+<kbd>G</kbd>﻿﻿  is the only way to do that I could think of.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to the question per se, but I've used and beta tested (unpaid) [Path Finder](http://cocoatech.com/pathfinder/) in the past, it provides a more intensive/technical Finder than the OS X Finder.

Some of the features that I prefer, among many:

- Tabbed Finder
- Path dropdowns (like Windows 7 Explorer)
- Dual panes
- Easy access to metadata

Comment: so does Path Finder allow you to edit the path? I have been using the FinderPath with regular finder, but I find that it comes nowhere near Dolphin  (linux) that I used to use.